# Gem to crop image to multiple sizes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When the user updates an image, I would like to crop it to different sizes to suit different specifications in the application like a bigger size image for profile page, a smaller image for comments etc. Is there any gem available for this in rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to use the [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for this. With it, you can define several sizes for your image. You do need to have ImageMagick installed for this to work. Your ruby model would have a line like this:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "150x150>", :medium => "400x400#", :large => "640x640" }
```

The default behavior is to resize to the smallest dimension and keep the aspect ratio. You can use some options to change this:

1. trailing #, thumbnail will be centrally cropped, ensuring the requested dimensions.
2. trailing >, thumbnail will only be modified if it is currently larger requested dimensions.

In your code you can then request the image using `image_tag @model.image.url(:small)` in your view.

Ryan bates has an excellent [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip) on this if you want more information. Paperclip also has an extensive wiki on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Try [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) to work with attaches

Also you can checkout ImageMagick, RMagick or ImageScience projects

Answer (score 0):

The most lightweight image manipulation library/gem that I know of is [Devil](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/the-devil-image-library-for-ruby/). ImageMagick/Cairo can be a pain to install. I've never had any problems with DeviL. Cheers.